# div alignment and issues with float

Tags: html, css

I'm recreating the AACC website (page [here](http://www.aacc.nche.edu/Pages/default.aspx)) and have run into some issues with trying to align the columns in the middle, titled "National Initiative", "Leading Advancement", and "Awards Program". In my source code, which is viewable with the css [here](http://www.sinc.stonybrook.edu/stu/csclement/hw4/hw4.html), I created it so that the banner with the clinton picture floats to the left of the login area and the side bar. However regarless if I use clear:both, the first column (which is viewable at the bottom of my page), stays underneath the sidebar on the right. I'm not entirely sure how to fix this, maybe I'm just putting the clear property in the wrong place in the code or whatever the problem may be. Just could use a fresh set of eyes on this.

Here's the CSS code where I think the problem could be corrected:

```css
#banner {
  float: left;
  width: 730px;
}

#logbar {
  background-color: rgb(95, 193, 47);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 740px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 130px;
}

#sidebar {
  margin-left: 740px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 700px;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: #66CC66;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

#col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 236;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(204, 227, 251);
}
```

Comment: Everything seems fine to me.. Could you show us a screenshot? What browser you are facing this issue on - also let us know the browser version and OS you are on.

Comment: Here's the issue: http://s12.postimg.org/k024g05zx/mywork.jpg and here's what it should look like: http://s17.postimg.org/s8pdkilgv/original_site.jpg

I'm using FF but also tried it in IE. Don't think browser compatibility is an issue. Also I'm using Vista 64 bit

Comment: It would be much better if you can demonstrate your problem, with code, on JSFiddle or CodePen :)

Comment: I provided the webpage where all my work is above, but you can view everything (work so far and source code) here too http://www.sinc.stonybrook.edu/stu/csclement/hw4/hw4.html Everyone is probably confused since I'm trying to recreate the webpage for the AACC.

Comment: @TeamRival as Terry says, putting the code into jsFiddle or CodePen will make it much easier for people to suggest edits that will fix your problem.  It's not just about being able to view the code; it's about being able to make changes to it without having to replicate everything on our own machines.

Comment: ah I see. I'm actually not working off of the latest version of the website, just a copy that my professor had set up so all the images are local to my PC. I'll definitely keep this in mind for the next time I have any questions.

Comment: @TeamRival links are now dead - I suggest updating your question to include updated links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can see that being possible with your HTML structure is absolutely positioning the element.

```
#col1 {
  top: 420px;           /* Add this */
  position: absolute;   /* And this */
  width: 236px;
  background-color: rgb(204, 227, 251);
}
```

However this is really just a hack. You should restructure your HTML. AACC is not a good example - they use tables for their layout. Look at how stackoverflow create their sidebar for a better example.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. Yeah this is by far the hardest HW we've had, especially since this can be replicated fairly easily in Dreamweaver just by setting up a table and merging columns and rows. I know absolute positioning is a big last resort but I think in this case it will be the best course of action. Don't want to have to recode everything else, would be very time consuming. Thanks again!